# OCaml cons (::) operator?

Tags: ocaml, cons

In OCaml, is there a way to refer to the cons operator by itself?

For example, I can use `(+)` and `( * )` as `int -> int -> int` functions, but I cannot use `(::)` as a `'a -> 'a list -> 'a list` function, as the following example show:

```
# (+) 3 5;;
- : int = 8
# ( * ) 4 6;;
- : int = 24
# (::) 1 [2;3;4];;
Error: Syntax error: operator expected.
```

Is there a way to produce a result like `(::)` other than with `fun x y -> x::y`? And does anyone know why `(::)` wasn't implemented in OCaml?

Comment: It would work if you surround the arguments with parenthesis, like so: `(::) (1, [2; 3; 4]);;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.  Cons (::) is a constructor, constructors can not be infix operators.  The allowed infix symbols are here:

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-caml-light/node4.9.html

Some workarounds are (as you mention) the verbose

```
(fun x l -> x :: l)
```

and defining your own nontraditional infix cons

```
let (+:) x l = x :: l
```

Comment: For reference, the knowledge is introduced by [http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/expr.html#toc50] section Variants.

Answer (score 16):

Adding to the answer of @seanmcl,

Actually OCaml supports a prefix form of (::):

```
# (::)(1, []);;
- : int list = [1]
```

This is in the uncurried form, corresponding with the fact that all the OCaml variant constructors are not curried and cannot be partially applied. This is handled by a special parsing rule just for (::), which is why you got a rather strange error message `Error: Syntax error: operator expected.`.

Update:

Upcoming OCaml 4.02 removes this parsing rule, therefore this is no longer available.

Comment: This is still working in 4.11 so did it not get removed after all?

Answer (score 7):

As of Ocaml 4.03, you can now use `cons` (in the [List](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) module). That is, `cons x xs` is the same as `x :: xs`.

Answer (score -1):

It's also possible to just define your own cons function:

`let cons = fun a list -> a :: list`

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think this answer is subsumed by that of @seanmcl (which shows that you can define your own function) and that of @JohnWickerson (which says that such a function named `cons` already exists in the standard library).

Comment: True, sorry to reiterate that's my bad